# Hibernate select groupProperty , rowCount with rowCount > n?

Tags: hibernate, criteria, detachedcriteria

Sorry if it is a dumb question but I've stuck with this problem for a whole afternoon but cannot find a solution because I'm not skilled with complicated SQL :

I want to find "**Top n message-sending users from a table with msg sent count > threshold**" , this is my criteria :

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Message.class);
ProjectionList plist = Projections.projectionList();
plist.add(Projections.groupProperty("user"));
plist.add(Projections.rowCount() , "count");
c.setProjection(plist);
c.addOrder(Order.desc("count"));

c.setFirstResult(0);
c.setMaxResults(count);
```

This is what I can write , but it lacks of "**filtering rows with rowCount lower than some threshold**". How to implement it with criteria ? Thanks a lot !

-------------- updated ------------------------

Thanks @TheStijn , I tried . I now can use subquery to achieve my goal , but the generated query is **not so clever** ! See the generated SQL :

```
select
    this_.fromUser as y0_,
    count(*) as y1_ 
from
    Message this_ 
where
    this_.fromUser is not null 
    and this_.created>? 
    and this_.created<? 
    and ? <= (
        select
            count(*) as y0_ 
        from
            Message msg_ 
        where
            msg_.fromUser=this_.fromUser 
            and msg_.fromUser is not null 
            and msg_.created>? 
            and msg_.created<?
    ) 
group by
    this_.fromUser 
order by
    y1_ desc limit ?
```

That is , the **subquery repeats most of the main query** , which I think it is a little redundant . Is there any criteria that builds such SQL queries :

```
select
    this_.fromUser as y0_,
    count(*) as y1_ 
from
    Message this_ 
where
    this_.fromUser is not null 
    and this_.created>? 
    and this_.created<? 
    and y1_ > ? // threshold
group by
    this_.fromUser 
order by
    y1_ desc limit ?
```

Thanks a lot !

(It seems much easier to use HQL to do this , but I am curious about the Criteria way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need an additional subquery like:

```
    DetachedCriteria subQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Message.class, "msg");
    subQuery.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("msg.user", "mainQuerymsg.user"));
    subQueryEntriesCount.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());

    c.add(Subqueries.lt(1L, subQuery));
```

*mainQuerymsg < your main criteria so you'ill need to create these criteria with an alias `createCriteria(MEssage.class, "alias")`*

Comment: Hi , I tried , but got a 'not so clever' SQL query . Would you please take a look at it again ? Thanks .

Comment: You can't do something in hibernate which is not possible in sql. Since you can't use an aggregation variable in your where clause in sql (not in any database I know at least) you won't be able to to this in hibernate). If your above sql is working please inform me which DB you're using.