# Hibernate Subquery with group by function

Tags: hibernate, group-by, subquery

Can you please let me how to execute following query through hibernate?

```
select count(empid) from (select empid, count(deptid) dept_count from emp group by empid) where dept_count > 1
```

Basically the query retrieves number of employee which are associated with more than 1 department.

Have created a DetachedCriteria for the subquery with group by function as below:

```
        DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Emp.class);
        ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();
        pl.add(Projections.groupProperty("empid"), "empid");
        pl.add(Projections.rowCount(), "dept_count");
        dc.setProjection(pl);
```

But then not finding a way to count number of employee with dept_count greater than 1.

Comment: please add your detachedCriteria code

Comment: Have added the detached criteria. Thanks!

Comment: please test this line I did not test it dc.add(Restriction.gt("depth_count","1") ; and also maybe need to create alias for this fields    and also check this link : [subquery for detachedcriteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602490/hibernate-criteria-perform-join-in-subquery-detachedcriteria) and also check this link its also what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416540/hibernate-select-groupproperty-rowcount-with-rowcount-n

Comment: Hi Mithat, it's not working. Appreciate if you can provide a working code if possible.

Comment: Please post all your code i will add working code